# How check if website support http, htts and www prefix with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrapy to check, if some website works fine, when I use `http://example.com`, `https://example.com` or `http://www.example.com`. When I create scrapy request, it works fine. for example, on my `page1.com`, it is always redirected to `https://`. I need to get this information as return value, or is there better way how to get this information using scrapy?

```
class myspider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'superspider'

    start_urls = [
        "https://page1.com/"
    ]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        url = response.url
        # removing all possible prefixes from url
        for remove in ['https://', 'http://', 'www.']:
            url = str(url).replace(remove, '').rstrip('/')

        # Try with all possible prefixes
        for prefix in ['http://', 'http://www.', 'https://', 'https://www.']:
            yield scrapy.Request(url='{}{}'.format(prefix, url), callback=self.test, dont_filter=True)

    def test(self, response):
        print(response.url, response.status)
```

The output of this spider is this:

```
https://page1.com 200
https://page1.com/ 200
https://page1.com/ 200
https://page1.com/ 200
```

This is nice, but I would like to get this information as return value to know, that e.g. on `http` is response code 200 and than save it to dictionary for later processing or save it as json to file(using items in scrapy).

DESIRED OUTPUT:
I would like to have dictionary named `a` with all information:

```
print(a)
{'https://': True, 'http://': True, 'https://www.': True, 'http://www.': True}
```

Later I would like to scrape more information, so I will need to store all information under one object/json/...

Comment: Would you be able to update a desired output?

Comment: I inserted desired output. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the meta possibility which was pointed out by eLRuLL you can parse  request.url:

```
scrapy shell http://stackoverflow.com
In [1]: request.url
Out[1]: 'http://stackoverflow.com'

In [2]: response.url
Out[2]: 'https://stackoverflow.com/'
```

To store the values for different runs together in one dict/json you can use an additional pipeline like mentioned in https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#duplicates-filter 
So you have something like:

```
Class WriteAllRequests(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.urldic={}

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        urldic[item.url]={item.urlprefix=item.urlstatus}
        if len(urldic[item.url])==4:
            # think this can be passed to a standard pipeline with a higher number
            writedata (urldic[item.url])

            del urldic[item.url]
```

You must additionally activate the pipeline

Comment: As I mentioned above, I know how to check and print it, the question is, how to get return value from function and store it , e.g. as dictionary. When I get to `callback` function, there can be processed code, but it do not return anything. one of the option is to store it inside e.g. to redis and when I will return from callback, I could read it and save it, it could work but according to me, it is not hte best way how to solve it.

Comment: Ok, your issue is that you want to store the values of 4 different runs in one dict/json ... so I changed my answer

Answer (score 0):

you are doing one extra request at the beginning of the spider and you could deal with all those domains with the `start_requests` method:

```
class myspider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'superspider'

    def start_requests(self):
        url = response.url
        # removing all possible prefixes from url
        for remove in ['https://', 'http://', 'www.']:
            url = str(url).replace(remove, '').rstrip('/')

        # Try with all possible prefixes
        for prefix in ['http://', 'http://www.', 'https://', 'https://www.']:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url='{}{}'.format(prefix, url), 
                callback=self.parse, 
                dont_filter=True, 
                meta={'prefix': prefix},
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {response.meta['prefix']: True}
```

check that I am using the `meta` request parameter to pass the information to the next callback method on which prefix was used.

Comment: And how to store `{response.meta['prefix']: True}` in some variable, lets say, variable `myprefixes` in start_requests function? Where is your reponse.meta yielded when you call parse function?